# Alguem me consegue explicar o que este código faz linha a linha?

Tags: c

```
void primeiro(int a) {
  a *= 2;
  printf("%d", a);
}

void segundo(int *u) {
 int x = 1;
  x = x + *u;
  primeiro(x);
  *u = x++;
}
int main() {
  int x = 5;
  segundo(&x);
  printf(":%d\n", x);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

O código começa por definir a variável `x` como inteiro com o valor `5` e chama a função `segundo` com o endereço de memoria da variável `x`:

```
int main() { 
    int x = 5;
    segundo(&x);
```

Nesta função `segundo` é criada outra variável `x` com o valor `1`:

```
void segundo(int *u) {
    int x = 1;
```

A essa variável é adicionado o valor apontado pelo ponteiro `u`. Este ponteiro foi o que foi passado no `main` e por isso aponta para o `x` do `main`, que tem o valor `5`:

```
x = x + *u;
```

Irá assim guardar `6` na variável `x` da função `segundo`. Agora chama-se a função `primeiro` passando esta variável `x`:

```
primeiro(x);
```

Na função `primeiro` multiplicamos o valor recebido por `2`, que será `6*2` e mostramos com `printf`:

```
void primeiro(int a) {
    a *= 2;
    printf("%d", a);
}
```

Esta variável `a` é uma copia do `x` que foi passado da função anterior, logo a multiplicação não altera esse valor.

Terminada esta função retomamos na função `segundo` a seguir à instrução `primeiro(x);` que já foi executada, restando apenas fazer a instrução:

```
*u = x++;
```

Que indica que o valor apontado por `u` passa a ser `x` (que já era) e que `x` apos esta instrução aumenta. Mas este `x` é uma variável local e por isso este pós incremento não tem efeito real uma vez que não existem mais instruções nesta função.

Depois de serem executadas as duas funções é escrito o `printf` no `main` com o valor de `x` que será `6`:

```
int main() {
    ...
    printf(":%d\n", x);
```

A [saída na consola de toda a execução do programa](https://ideone.com/UEfUWv) é:

```
12:6
```

Answer (score 0):

```
void primeiro(int a) { // Função sem retorno, com parâmetro do tipo inteiro.
  a *= 2; // a recebe um valor inteiro e multiplica por 2.
  printf("%d", a); // Exibe o resultado na tela, formatado como decimal "%d".
}

void segundo(int *u) { // Função sem retorno, com ponteiro como parâmetro.
 int x = 1; // Variável x recebe o valor inteiro 1.
  x = x + *u; // x recebe o valor de x + o valor do ponteiro, passado por referência.
  primeiro(x); // Chama a função primeiro() e passa o resultado de x.
  *u = x++; // O ponteiro recebe um incremento inteiro. O valor atual + 1.
}
int main() { // Função principal
  int x = 5; // Variável x recebe o valor inteiro 5.
  segundo(&x); // Passa o valor da variável x para a função segundo() por referência.
  printf(":%d\n", x); // Exibe o valor da variável x com as alterações feitas pela função segundo().
}
```